# module-for-acceptance using old project directory

Tags: ember.js, npm, bower, ember-cli, yarnpkg

Might need a little context here... I copied files from an older Ember project into a fresh directory to continue working on it.  Mistake.  I have most everything cleaned up after playing with nvm, bower, yarn, etc.  There is one remaining flaw.  When I run `ember test --server`, I have a lingering message that refuses to go away.  I've updated my environment.js file with the name of the new project, I've scoured project.json, bower.json, etc.  I ran yarn.  Still the error persists.  I've cleared both npm and bower caches, and installed fresh, deleted my node_modules and bower_components folders...  I am getting annoyed at this point.

And here is the full mess I've been getting (more or less):

```
Died on test #1     at TestLoader.moduleLoadFailure (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6468:11)
    at TestLoader.require (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:69:14)
    at TestLoader.loadModules (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:58:18)
    at Function.TestLoader.load (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:89:24)
    at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6477:16: Could not find module `new-project-directory/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance` imported from `old-project-directory/tests/acceptance/game-test`@ 2 ms
Source:     
Error: Could not find module `new-project-directory/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance` imported from `old-project-directory/tests/acceptance/game-test`
    at missingModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:237:11)
    at findModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:248:7)
    at Module.findDeps (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:182:24)
    at findModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:252:11)
    at requireModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:35:15)
    at TestLoader.require (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:67:9)
    at TestLoader.loadModules (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:58:18)
    at Function.TestLoader.load (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:89:24)
    at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6477:16
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing.  I hadn't deleted the tests folder.  Once that was completed, everything is back to normal.  After deleting the tests directory, and running `ember init` again, I'm back to seeing sane test failures.